# Unsupported major.minor version despite using correct Java version

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm running a script that uses Eclipse and I am seeing this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: my/file/path/goes/here/CreateEcoreFile : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Some googling led me to believe that I was perhaps trying to compile a Java 7 project with a Java 8 compiler. I have checked my system (Cent OS 6) and I only have Java 7 installed, I even downgraded my Eclipse to Neon 1.A and it's build path is Java 7.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35866015/1602555) version 52.0 means Java 8. Eclipse uses it's own [ECJ compiler](https://blog.deepakazad.com/2010/05/ecj-eclipse-java-compiler.html) which is part of the IDE, which probably uses Java 8 as default.

Follow [this guide](https://www.concretepage.com/ide/eclipse/how-to-change-eclipse-java-version-for-compiler-and-jre) and set the Java compiler version for your project to Java 7:

1. Go to Window -> Preferences
2. Go to Java -> Compiler
3. Select Compiler compliance level

Comment: I don't have a "Project facets" option in my properties window

Comment: I guess this will depend on your Eclipse version and plugins, I added a different guide but it's guessing. Refer to Eclipse docs.

Comment: Your last update is exactly the solution, thank you!