# opencv in eclipse java

Tags: java, opencv

For the past 2 hours have been struggling with this error tried using java 11 as default but the error doesn't seem to be fixed.
it gives the error below:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/opencv/core/Core has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates your trying to use Java 8 instead of Java 11. See also [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)
Is the compiler version correctly set in your project settings?