# Error Importing tables from mysql to hadoop using sqoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I'm a newbie and I am trying initiate an import processing from a linux command line: to import a table from mysql to hdfs using sqoop but I seem to be experiencing some errors and import fails, even though my Java version is 1.8. I have studied the error codes to identify what the problem is but I seem not to understand it . Here is my code and the error I am having

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --username root --password 'root' --table lee --target-dir sqoop/lee2;
```

Error Code

```
Warning: /usr/lib/hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
20/07/27 11:03:01 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.3-cdh4.7.1
20/07/27 11:03:01 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
20/07/27 11:03:01 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
20/07/27 11:03:01 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
20/07/27 11:03:02 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `lee` AS t LIMIT 1
20/07/27 11:03:02 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `lee` AS t LIMIT 1
20/07/27 11:03:02 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-training/compile/705c3feafe814917756c3176da85c34f/lee.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
20/07/27 11:03:03 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-training/compile/705c3feafe814917756c3176da85c34f/lee.jar
20/07/27 11:03:03 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
20/07/27 11:03:03 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
20/07/27 11:03:03 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
20/07/27 11:03:03 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
20/07/27 11:03:03 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of lee
20/07/27 11:03:03 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
20/07/27 11:03:04 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
20/07/27 11:03:04 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
20/07/27 11:03:04 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.YarnClientImpl is inited.
20/07/27 11:03:04 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.YarnClientImpl is started.
20/07/27 11:03:06 INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: SELECT MIN(`id`), MAX(`id`) FROM `lee`
20/07/27 11:03:06 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:3
20/07/27 11:03:06 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
20/07/27 11:03:06 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.cache.files.timestamps is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.files.timestamps
20/07/27 11:03:06 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
20/07/27 11:03:06 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.inputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.inputformat.class
20/07/27 11:03:06 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.outputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.outputformat.class
20/07/27 11:03:06 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
20/07/27 11:03:06 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
20/07/27 11:03:06 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.cache.files is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.files
20/07/27 11:03:06 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
20/07/27 11:03:06 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.job.classpath.files is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.classpath.files
20/07/27 11:03:06 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
20/07/27 11:03:06 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
20/07/27 11:03:06 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1595623626771_0002
20/07/27 11:03:06 INFO client.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1595623626771_0002 to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
20/07/27 11:03:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://hadoop:8088/proxy/application_1595623626771_0002/
20/07/27 11:03:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1595623626771_0002
20/07/27 11:03:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1595623626771_0002 running in uber mode : false
20/07/27 11:03:14 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
20/07/27 11:03:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1595623626771_0002_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: lee : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
20/07/27 11:03:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1595623626771_0002_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
Error: lee : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
20/07/27 11:03:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1595623626771_0002_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: lee : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
20/07/27 11:03:32 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1595623626771_0002_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: lee : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
20/07/27 11:03:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1595623626771_0002_m_000002_1, Status : FAILED
Error: lee : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
20/07/27 11:03:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1595623626771_0002_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: lee : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
20/07/27 11:03:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1595623626771_0002_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: lee : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
20/07/27 11:03:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1595623626771_0002_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: lee : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
20/07/27 11:03:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1595623626771_0002_m_000002_2, Status : FAILED
Error: lee : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
20/07/27 11:03:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 33% reduce 0%
20/07/27 11:03:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1595623626771_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1595623626771_0002_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

20/07/27 11:03:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 8
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=10
        Launched map tasks=12
        Other local map tasks=12
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=80903
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
20/07/27 11:03:51 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
20/07/27 11:03:51 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 46.4433 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
20/07/27 11:03:51 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
20/07/27 11:03:51 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!
```

Comment: You need to use JDK version 1.8. Does this answer your question? [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Comment: @mazaneicha java version is 1.8 or what are you referring to please

Comment: The error that you're getting `Unsupported major.minor version 52` says that JVM that runs (most likely 1.7) does not support version with which the classes were compiled (1.8). Why are you using cdh 4.7.1 by the way? its ancient!

Comment: @mazaneicha please how do I resolve this?