# Tomcat 8.5.69: Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException]

Tags: java, tomcat

I have installed Apache Tomcat/8.5.69 | with JVM version 1.7.0_201-b00 on Ubuntu 14.04.

And successfully run tomcat on browser but whenever I tried to deploy any application it is showing me the below error:

FAIL - Application at context path [/oXygenLicenseServlet] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/oXygenLicenseServlet]]]

It is working fine on my local system (which has ubuntu v20 and with tomcat 9) but not working on dev server.

In the server log file I received the below error:

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/xerces/impl/xs/XMLSchemaValidator : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 tomcat

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: The version of `xercesImpl` you use requires Java 8 or later.