# Javadoc unskippable

Tags: maven, java-7, javadoc

In my project, I am trying to skip javadoc plugin entirely when running `mvn --batch-mode clean release:prepare` and `mvn --batch-mode release:perform`. Yet, adding

```
    <properties>
        <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
    </properties>
```

does not prevent javadoc from being executed. I don't even ever mention javadoc in root pom.xml. Using maven option `-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true` or `-Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true"` doesn't help either.

My pom.xml does not have parent poms. The version of maven-javadoc-plugin is displayed as 3.3.0.

The error I am trying to address is:

```
[INFO] java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.JavadocJar not present
... the usual part of mess of a stack trace skipped ...
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/plugins/javadoc/JavadocJar : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
[INFO]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

I did not even define the `<plugin>` part in the config to run javadoc. Interestingly, adding the following snipped still causes 3.3.0 javadoc to be ran!

```
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
      </plugin>
```

What else can be attempted to disable the javadoc plugin from running entirely?

Comment: Weird, according this doc it should get skipped: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#skip
Are you sure you're using a recent version of the javadoc plugin that has that feature?

Comment: Does your project POM extend a `<parent>`? And if yes, does that POM (or one of its parents...) hardcode that property to false, e.g. `<maven.javadoc.skip>false</maven.javadoc.skip>`, either in `<properties>` or directly in a plugin config block? This type of config would prevent the property setting from having any effect.

Comment: @user944849 My pom.xml does not have parent poms.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet The version of maven-javadoc-plugin is displayed as 3.3.0.

The error I am trying to address is edited into the question now.

I did not even define the <plugin> part in the config to run javadoc. Interestingly, adding the following snipped still causes 3.3.0 javadoc to be ran!

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
      </plugin>

Comment: Pls run `mvn help:effective-pom` and report the javadoc-plugin related snippets

Comment: @guido       
inside the build block:
`<plugin> <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId<version>2.7</version</plugin>`
Inside the properties block:
`<maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>`

Comment: just noticed you are using maven-release; maven-release runs mvn in mvn for you (preforming the release), you need to add the `-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true` as an argument in the configuration for maven-release-plugin. Check here: https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#arguments

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have *this* error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/plugins/javadoc/JavadocJar : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
[INFO]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

which means that the version of Java you use to run Maven with is too old.  See [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22489398/53897) for details.

Fix this so the javadoc plugin loads properly and then can recognize the system property you provide and not do anything further.